# Excel counting the number of unique occurrences after matching the name with corresponding category

Tags: excel

Need help with matching Teacher with students and counting only a single occurrence of students from the column. Output to include the number of occurrences and the corresponding country of residence.

Expected output:

```
               Teacher Place   No
               Iwin    London  3
                       Newyork 1
               Rice    Newyork 1
                       Germany 1
                       Britan  1
                       Brazil  2
```

Input:

```
                Name  students  Place
                Iwin    John    London
                Iwin    John    London
                Iwin    Ron     London
                Iwin    Emil    Newyork
                Rice    Jacob   Newyork
                Rice    Rui     Germany
                Rice    erin    Britan
                Rice    erin    Britan
                Rice    erin    Britan
                Rice    josh    Brazil
                Iwin    Gary    London
                Rice    Meca    Brazil
```

Comment: Hello, what have you tried?

Comment: I am trying with Countif and Vlookup but unable to deal with the repeat items.

Answer (score 2):

You could make a unique list, take it to a table and then make a pivot table.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
A16 =UNIQUE(CHOOSECOLS(UNIQUE(A2:C13);1;3))
C16 =SUM((A16&B16=($F$3:$F$11&$H$3:$H$11))*1)
```

To get the outcome exact as you want you can hide the Names which occure more than one with conditional formating. Make the text color white or to change the numberformat of the cell to something like this:

```
;;;
```

[image]

This picture shows the conditional formatting.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To get the counts you can `textjoin` the name, students and place columns for each row. Let say the input data you've provided starts in column `A` row `1`, the formula would look like this:

```
=TEXTJOIN("_",, A2:C2)
```

You should get this `Iwin_John_London` in cell where you put the function. Lets say we put it in column `D` row `2`. Now, you `autofill` for the rest of the rows and then use `unique` on the recently created output:

```
=UNIQUE(D2:D13)
```

Now we can extract the teacher's name and the place from the unique column we created. Lets say it the unique data starts in column `E` row `2`. The formula would look like this:

```
=TEXTJOIN("_",, LEFT(E2, SEARCH("_", E2,1)-1), RIGHT(E2, LEN(E2) - SEARCH("_", E2, SEARCH("_", E2)+1)))
```

You should get this for the first cell `Iwin_London`. We now have to do another `autofill`. Then a `unique` in the data we just outputted in column `F`.

```
=UNIQUE(F2:F10)
```

Finally, we can do a `countif` + `autofill` to find the desired counts with the data on column `G` and `F`:

```
=COUNTIF(F2:F10,G2)
```

This is what all the data should look like:
[image: excel_data]